# What is a Topological Twist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, topological-field-theory

I have come across topological twists on numerous occasions but I have never actually seen them explained in an understandable way. So, I was wondering

- What does it physically mean to topologically twist a theory?
- What does it mathematically mean to topologically twist a theory?
- What is the motivation for talking about topological twists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I've found an answer to my own question. One can take a supersymmetric theory defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$  and topologically twist it by redefining the rotation group of the theory into a mixture of the (spacetime) rotation group and the R-symmetry group.

Physically, this is just making one sector of the theory "more apparent". We can then restrict to this sector of the theory to get a topological field theory. In general, we will lose the supersymmetry (or at least lose some of it) since we are only considering one sector of the theory.

Comment: Could you possibly give any reference for self studying these ?

Comment: @chaveroche I have found these lecture notes https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0504147 quite pedagogical, although I am a bit of a novice myself, so there might be better references that I am unaware of.